# How to convert an ASCII int to string?

Tags: c++

recently I made a program that, given a string, the function returns its corresponding ascii code. For example, the string "h", the function returns an int 104. Now, I want to do the reverse process, ie, given an int, return its corresponding ascii character. For example, given the 104 int return the string "h". Please, help.

Comment: What did you try, and what problem did you run into?

Comment: `'h'` is just another way of writing `104`, similar to `0x68` or `0150`. Your confusion stems from the difference between `'h'` being a value and `"h"` being an array of values.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [string constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), we can see one that takes a count and a character value. So we can use that:

```
return std::string(1, ascii_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a whole string for this. Given that you're looking for a single character, the correct type to use is a `char`:

`int x = 65;
char xc = (char)x;
assert(xc == 'A');`

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
...
std::string mystring(1, c);
```